# Debug Logs missing in sandbox for specified Users in Salesforce

Tags: debugging, salesforce

In our sandbox I have included following three Users with log level as Finer/Finest.
1. my UserId (Admin) 
2. Site User ID 
3. Integration UserID used to access salesforce from Java env.

I can see the debug logs for my UserID while doing something in salesforce but while accessing pages from Site or accessing salesforce from Java application  not getting any debug logs for Site User or Integrated User.

This was not happening earlier and observed in last few weeks.
Please let me know if anyone have gone through this situation and the steps to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

download this chrome plugin : [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)
You can only capture debug logs for a Guest User if the browser being used has a specific cookie enabled.

1. Go to your site/vf page
2. press F12
3. Go to EditThisCookie Tab
4. select Name change it to ***debug_logs***  and value change it to ***debug_logs***  where **DomainName Contains .force.com .**